# Write syscall in shellcode does not print to stdout

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, system-calls, shellcode

I am trying to learn about shellcode and system calls by injecting a simple "hello world" shellcode into a program that reads and executes code from an environment variable.

The shellcode is executed but does not print to stdout even though `strace` informs me that the correct syscall is performed:

```
>nasm helloworld1.asm
>export SHELLCODE=$(cat helloworld1.asm)
>strace ./vuln
write(1, "hello, wurld!\n\r", 15)       = ?                                                 │~                                                                                           
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Modifying the shellcode to use the `syscall` instruction rather than `int 0x80` resolves the issue.

**My question is:** Why does my shellcode not print to stdout even though the write syscall is called with the correct parameters?

**The target program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    void (*funptr)() = NULL;

    funptr = getenv("SHELLCODE");

    funptr();
}
```

Compiled with gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -no-pie -o vuln vuln.c.

**Shellcode that does not write to stdout**

```
BITS 64
section .data

section .text

global _start
jmp end
trick:
pop rsi        ; Put address of msg into source register      
; SYSCALL WRITE(1, msg, 15)
xor rax, rax
add rax, 1     ; Put syscall 1 (write) into register a
xor rdi, rdi   ; Zero destination register
inc rdi        ; put stdin fd (1) into destination register
xor rdx, rdx   ; zero register d
add rdx, 15    ; put length of string into register d
int 0x80       ; perform syscall

; SYSCALL EXIT(1)
xor rdi, rdi   ; put return code 0 into destination register
xor rax, rax   ; zero register a
add rax, 60    ; move syscall (exit=60) into register a
int 0x80       ; perform syscall

end:
call trick     ; call to go back to trick which pushes address of msg onto the stack
msg     db        "hello, wurld!", 0x0a, 0x0d      ; The string and newline char + CR
```

**Shellcode that writes to stdout:**

```
BITS 64        
section .data 

section .text  

global _start 
jmp end
trick:
pop rsi        ; Put address of msg into source register      
; SYSCALL WRITE(1, msg, 15)
xor rax, rax
add rax, 1     ; move syscall 1 (write) into register a
xor rdi, rdi   ; Zero destination register 
inc rdi        ; put stdin fd (1) into destination register
xor rdx, rdx   ; zero register d
add rdx, 15    ; put length of string into register d
syscall        ; perform syscall

; SYSCALL EXIT(1)
xor rdi, rdi   ; put return code 0 into destination register
xor rax, rax   ; move system call 0 into register a
add rax, 60    ; move syscall (exit=60) into register a
syscall        ;  perform syscall

end:
call trick     ; go back and push the next address (msg) onto the stack
msg     db        "hello, wurld!", 0x0a, 0x0d
```

Comment: TL;DR: your addresses got truncated.  Don't use `int 0x80` in 64 bit code.

Comment: Why `xor rax, rax ... Add rax, 60`? Instead of the simple `mov rax, 60`